# Level Order Traversion help needed, getting error

Tags: c#

I'm trying to figure out why I'm getting the following error from this hackerrank.com problem (https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/30-binary-trees/problem):

> solution.cs(32,7): error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `Node`, expecting
>   `class`, `delegate`, `enum`, `interface`, `partial`, or `struct`
>   Compilation failed: 1 error(s), 0 warnings
>
> Exit Status: 255

I've checked all the usual stuff like semicolons and curly brackets being closed, but I'm stumped.

The code I have is the following, and I've commented where the error starts:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
class Node{
    public Node left,right;
    public int data;
    public Node(int data){
        this.data=data;
        left=right=null;
    }
}
class Solution{
    static Queue<Node> nodeQueue = new Queue<Node>();
    static void levelOrder(Node root){
        //Write your code here
        nodeQueue.Enqueue(root);
        while (nodeQueue.Count > 0){
            var n = nodeQueue.Dequeue();
            Console.Write(n.data + " ");
            if (n.left != null) {
                nodeQueue.Enqeue(n.left);
            }
            if (n.right != null) {
                nodeQueue.Enqueue(n.right);
            }
        }
    }   
}
// Right here is where it is saying it's not expecting "NODE", the line below
    static Node insert(Node root, int data){
        if(root==null){
            return new Node(data);
        }
        else{
            Node cur;
            if(data<=root.data){
                cur=insert(root.left,data);
                root.left=cur;
            }
            else{
                cur=insert(root.right,data);
                root.right=cur;
            }
            return root;
        }
    }
    static void Main(String[] args){
        Node root=null;
        int T=Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        while(T-->0){
            int data=Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            root=insert(root,data);            
        }
        levelOrder(root);

    }
}
```

Comment: Your static `insert` method isn't part of any class.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli thank you! I'll adjust it now

Comment: @EvanTrimboli that was it! I had one too many brackets apparently, thinking I needed to close out the class a bit too early. Thank you.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli could you submit it as an answer so I can give you credit?

Comment: Would suggest you just delete it, I don't think the question as-is provides much value.

Answer (score 0):

I copied your code into a default Console Application and it built without errors for me.

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Linq;
    class Node
    {
        public Node left, right;
        public int data;
        public Node(int data)
        {
            this.data = data;
            left = right = null;
        }
    }
    class Solution
    {
        static Queue<Node> nodeQueue = new Queue<Node>();
        static void levelOrder(Node root)
        {
            //Write your code here
            nodeQueue.Enqueue(root);
            while (nodeQueue.Count > 0)
            {
                var n = nodeQueue.Dequeue();
                Console.Write(n.data + " ");
                if (n.left != null)
                {
                    nodeQueue.Enqueue(n.left);
                }
                if (n.right != null)
                {
                    nodeQueue.Enqueue(n.right);
                }
            }
        }

    // Right here is where it is saying it's not expecting "NODE", the line below
        static Node insert(Node root, int data)
        {
            if (root == null)
            {
                return new Node(data);
            }
            else
            {
                Node cur;
                if (data <= root.data)
                {
                    cur = insert(root.left, data);
                    root.left = cur;
                }
                else
                {
                    cur = insert(root.right, data);
                    root.right = cur;
                }
                return root;
            }
        }
        static void Main(String[] args)
        {
            Node root = null;
            int T = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            while (T-- > 0)
            {
                int data = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                root = insert(root, data);
            }
            levelOrder(root);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @EvanTrimboli pointed out that I had one too many brackets, closing the class early. Thank you for this though!